# echo a JSON environment variable in a makefile

Tags: json, makefile, environment-variables

If I do this

```
user $ export JSON='
{
    "key":"val"
}
'
```

and then in my Makefile I do

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo ${JSON}
```

I get the following error:

```
user $ make test

/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [Makefile:166: test] Error 1
```

I guess I can do

```
user $ export JSON='{"key":"val"}'
```

and

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo '${JSON}'
```

which works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to have recognized, the problem is with the (lack of) quoting.  In conjunction with that, it makes a difference whether you have `make` expand the variable reference or defer it for the shell to perform (which is an option for an environment variable, but not for a `make` variable).  `make` expands the variable and *then* attempts to split the recipe into lines.  The newlines in the variable's value interfere with that.

But for an environment variable such as this, you can work around a variety of problems by deferring expansion to the shell by escaping the `$` to `make`:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo "$${JSON}"
```

The `$$` represents a literal `$` to `make`, and suppresses expansion of variable `JSON`.  The resulting shell command contains a double-quoted expansion of the variable, which accommodates all manner of special characters in the variable's value, including newlines and double quotes.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks!